# Tables in the Charts example have no frames

Tags: c++, extjs, web, wt

I am new in Wt.
I installed Wt from

http://sourceforge.net/projects/witty/files/wt/3.3.5/Wt-3.3.5-rc2-msvs2013-Windows-x64-SDK.exe/download

with all the compiled binaries including the examples to my Win7 x64.
I didn't compile anything yet. I just noticed that the Charts example running at my PC looks different than nice and cute

http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/examples/charts/charts.wt

The tables don't have any frames. But reaction on clicks is there.
I have read that ExtJS must be added.
So (according to the instruction) I copied
ext-base.js and ext-all.js to Wt\examples\charts\
and everything from resources to Wt\examples\charts\resources\
It didn't help.
I also tried to copy them to Wt\examples\charts\ext\ and Wt\examples\charts\ext\resources\
It didn't help.
And the same for 3.3.4.
The folder tiny_mce was already in Wt\examples\charts\resources\
So I beleive I shouldn't do anything for it.

Do I miss anything or is it a bug?

UPDATE: On Win 8.1 it is the same.

But it seems to work fine on CentOS 6.6. I installed Wt 3.2.2 using

http://pkgs.org/centos-6/epel-x86_64/wt-3.2.2-6.p1.el6.x86_64.rpm.html

http://pkgs.org/centos-6/epel-x86_64/wt-examples-3.2.2-6.p1.el6.x86_64.rpm.html

So the problem must be specific to the Windows build.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't careful enough with command line arguments. It works now.